# Solving an equation involving the sine function

Tags: trigonometry

If $\pi/4 < a < \pi/2$, and $$4a - 2\sin(2a) = \pi,$$ then what is $a$?

I have used Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula , and I got $a \approx 1.154550755417921$,
but how can I find the exact value of $a$? Please help. Thanks

Comment: there is no exact value of $a$!

Comment: I know a is irrational but i need a better solving method and a better answer

Comment: $a$ is not just irrational, I could conjecture that it's transcendental and the only "better" definition of $a$ is the following [the root of "4x-2sin(x)=\pi"], when for exemple you say the answer is $\sqrt 2$ it's just a simplification of the "root of $x^2-2=0$" so other then an approximation or definition by the equation itself there is no other definition of $a$!

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Comment: Of course there is an exact value of $a$, @Elaqqad, what you mean is that there is no closed form expression for $a$ in terms of the functions ordinarily encountered in trigonometry classes.

Answer (score 0):

$$4a - 2\sin(2a) = \pi$$
$$\sin(2a)=2a-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Let  $x=2a-\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=x$$
$$\cos(x)=x$$
There is no standard closed form for the root of this equation.

Numerical calculus leads to an approximate :

$x \simeq 0.7390851332151606416553120876738734040134117589$

As a consequence, there is no standard closed form for the root of $4a - 2\sin(2a) = \pi$

$a=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\simeq 1.154940730005028630443316889656812423055998229$

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that Dottie number is root of $\cos x = x$

Comment: OK. more historical information :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html

Comment: Thanks again. So can we say Bhaskara's formula is so effective ? It gives $1.1545\dots$ and answer is $1.1549\dots$

Comment: All depends on what "effective" means. $a=1.1545$ is not a bad aproximate : $$4(1.1545)-\sin(2(1.1545))=3.1383$$ Of course, it is less accurate than $a=1.1549$ : $$4(1.1549)-\sin(2(1.1549))=3.14132$$